# Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default when running sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 18.10, official-repositories

I am running `sudo apt-get update` on my ubuntu 18.10

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

Then getting below response:

```
Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                                             
Ign:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                                             
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                                      
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease                                                                                                     
Hit:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:9 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                          
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                      
Ign:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease                                                                      
Get:13 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease [17.1 kB]                                                      
Hit:15 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                            
Ign:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease      
Err:13 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
Err:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
E: The repository 'https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

My sources.list

```
dev@dev-40-G2:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.10 _Cosmic Cuttlefish_ - Release amd64 (20181017.3)]/ cosmic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted
# deb-src http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic universe
# deb-src http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates universe
# deb-src http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic multiverse
# deb-src http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
# deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
# deb-src https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

I am new on Ubuntu - anyone assist? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, 18.10 reached an end of life, please upgrade to 19.10 or 20.04 LTS a month later.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing http://us.archive.ubuntu.com with http://old-releases.ubuntu.com everywhere in source.list file. That worked for me.

Comment: It would be much more useful to explain why one should do this, and what the suggested changes do. Asking people to blindly run commands or make changes is likely to encourage others with different (but perhaps similar-sounding) problems to blindly make the changes suggested here and possibly break their system.

Comment: Well, @Kurankat, you are right and since I was facing the same problem I just posted this answer out of eagerness. Well I have found a more reliable solution which actually worked for me. One can try to upgrade his or her system from 18.10 to 19.04. The one which worked for me is - [link to blog](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2020/02/21/upgrading-from-an-unsupported-ubuntu/). Hope it helps! And thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: should include the correct answer here with the steps to reproduce the answer AND why it works.   Do not only post a link.